# How to stop TRadioButton reacting at arrow keys?

Tags: delphi, radio-button, delphi-2009

I have a panel with a few `TRadioButton`s placed horizontally. If the most left button is focused and I press Left Arrow, the focus jumps to the most right button. I want to stop this behavoir for all arrows when they reach the edge. Is it possible ?
I tried overriding the `WM_KEYDOWN` but the buttons never receive this message when a arrow key is pressed.

```
  TRadioButton = class(StdCtrls.TRadioButton)
  protected
    procedure WMKeyDown(var Message: TWMKeyDown); message WM_KEYDOWN;
    procedure WMKeyUp(var Message: TWMKeyUp); message WM_KEYUP;
  public
    BlockLeft, BlockRight: Boolean;
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

constructor TRadioButton.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
 inherited;
 BlockLeft:= False;
 BlockRight:= False;
end;

procedure TRadioButton.WMKeyDown(var Message: TWMKeyDown);
begin
 if BlockLeft and (Message.CharCode = VK_LEFT) then Exit;
 if BlockRight and (Message.CharCode = VK_RIGHT) then Exit;

 inherited;
end;

procedure TRadioButton.WMKeyUp(var Message: TWMKeyUp);
begin
 if BlockLeft and (Message.CharCode = VK_LEFT) then Exit;
 if BlockRight and (Message.CharCode = VK_RIGHT) then Exit;
 inherited;
end;
```

Comment: Where/how did you try overriding `WM_KEYDOWN`? Can we see that code?

Comment: I edited and added the code.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I don't see how it's supposed to work. Both those variables are always going to evaluate to `False` based on the code I can see. Where do these actually get changed to `True`?

Comment: It is possible, but wouldn't be better to implement some kind of `TabWrap` property for the panel container? Btw. it's not just left and right arrow keys that can focus next or previous control; also up and down keys do that.

Comment: @JerryDodge, I set those variables to `True` in the `OnCreate` event of the containing `Form`.

Comment: This is dialog navigation. That's handled at a lower level. You need to intercept that.

Comment: I still don't see how that would work. You set them to `True` in the form's creation and `False` in the radio control's creation? How does that work? Shouldn't they be toggled at the moment user has reached the first/last control?

Comment: @Victoria, I will gladly implement anything, but I don't know what do you mean.

Comment: @JerryDodge, Of course, my code doesn't work. Those settings to `False` is for default. The only settings that matters is those from form's creation. But it won't work because `TRadioButton` doesn't receive messages for arrow keys.

Comment: You should try cn_keydown. Conceptually it would be wrong though, a control shouldn't care where it is placed. You should be handling the behavior at a lower level.

Comment: Thanks @SertacAkyuz ! It works with `CN_KEYDOWN`.

Comment: @Sertac, hence I was suggesting some kind of `TabWrap` property for the container, not for the particular control(s) placed inside. Marus, I was thinking about implementing only single property that would prevent focusing first or last control when you'd reach the end or start of the tab order list by pressing arrow key for the panel, not for radio button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VCL offsets keyboard messages to become a *control notification* and sends it to the message's destined control. Hence you should be intercepting a `CN_KEYDOWN` message instead.

If this is for a one time design consideration, I would prefer to handle this behavior at the form level since IMO a control, itself, shouldn't care where it is placed on. For a form where all radio buttons are expected to behave similar, an example could be:

```
procedure TForm1.CMDialogKey(var Message: TCMDialogKey);
begin
  if ActiveControl is TRadioButton then
    case Message.CharCode of
      VK_LEFT, VK_UP: begin
        if ActiveControl.Parent.Controls[0] = ActiveControl then begin
          Message.Result := 1;
          Exit;
        end;
      end;
      VK_RIGHT, VK_DOWN: begin
        if ActiveControl.Parent.Controls[ActiveControl.Parent.ControlCount - 1]
            = ActiveControl then begin
          Message.Result := 1;
          Exit;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  inherited;
end;
```

If this is not for a one time behavior, I'd go for writing a container control as Victoria  mentioned in the comments to the question.

Comment: Yes, it's for one time behavior. Thanks ! :)